# Int values get automatically converted into float values on Binding the text values in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting int values from the stored procedure. But when i bind this datasource with the gridview i am seeing the values being converted into float.
i am using **Text='<% # Bind("Quantity") %'** 

 I wanna that to be displayed as int, with out zero's
eg: let the value be 233, when i bind that its getting displayed as 233.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Text='<%# Bind("Quantity", "{0:0}") %>'
```

[This link](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) has a pretty complete list and explanation of the string formatting codes. They can be goofy sometimes, say with the double.ToString(*formatCode*) method:

```
var a = 12344.00;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("0"));
```

Outputs the same as this in binding syntax

```
Eval(12344.00, "{0:0}")
```